# Error message java? converting from string to another class?

Tags: java

I get an error message cannot convert from String to Movie.  Why do I get this error message what should I be returning in the first if statement.  Should I call the class Movie?

```
public Movie findMovieByName(String inTitle) {
    for (Movie movies : movieArray)
        if (inTitle == movies.getTitle())
            return movies.getTitle();
        else
            return null;
```

Comment: use `inTitle.equals(movies.getTitle())` instead.

Comment: it returns the movie title in the Movie class this is in a different class

Comment: Considering your method, you need to return a `Movie`, not a `String` - also, if the first movie in your array does not match, you are going to return null, which is probably not what you need.

Comment: @vishalK then I get an error message cannot convert from boolean to movie?

Comment: You should return `movies` instead of `movies.getTitle()`

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
public Movie findMovieByName(String inTitle) {
    for (Movie movie : movieArray) {
       if (inTitle.equals(movie.getTitle()) {
         return movie;
       }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Changes:

- Use `String.equals` for comparing `String` content. `==` compares object references
- Don't return `null` until you have checked *every* `Movie`

*Side Note:* A `Map<String, Movie>` could be used here instead if lookups are frequent.

Answer (score 1):

You have returned Title instead of movie

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues with your code:

The first one is here:

```
if (inTitle == movies.getTitle())
```

The == operator compares the instance of the String inTitle with the instance of the String returned by movies.getTitle(). But what you want to do is compare the characters contained in the two instances and see if they are the same. For this you should write:

```
if (inTitle.equals(movies.getTitle()))
```

The second problem is that your findMovieByName method should return an instance of Movie, but you are returning a String:

```
return movies.getTitle();
```

You should do the following instead:

```
return movies;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Movie findMovieByName(String inTitle) {
    for (Movie movies : movieArray){
        if (inTitle.equals(movies.getTitle())){
            return movies.getTitle();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

As I can see from your code, `movies.getTitle()` either returns a `Movie` or a `String` object.

But with your error message, I am very sure you meant `return movies` instead of `return movies.getTitle()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `movies.getTitle()` returns a string, you can (and should) use:

```
inTitle.compareTo(movies.getTitle()) == 0
```

And, of course, what's the point on returning the same title you are entering? Either you can return a `true` value, meaning the value of `inTitle` was found, or return the movie (which is what the definition of your procedure says. So, your procedure will look as follows:

```
public Movie findMovieByName(String inTitle) {
   for(Movie movies : moviesArray) {
       if (inTitle.compareTo(movies.getTitle()) == 0)
           return movies;
       else
           return null;
   }
}
```

You can also use `compareToIgnoreCase` if you want your comparison to be case-insensitive.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String) and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Hope this helps.